# Returning data with different types from a single method

Tags: c#

I am trying to find a way to simplify some code where I want to get data with different structures from one method.

I have the following code:

```
public class VmOne
{
    private ObservableCollection<Structure1> GetFirstStructCollection()
    {
        var myList = new List<Structure1>();
        myList.Add(new Structure1
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "John Doe",
            Description = "struct 1 test"
        });

        myList.Add(new Structure1
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Sally Doe",
            Description = "struct 1 test"
        });

        return new ObservableCollection<Structure1>(myList);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Structure2> GetSecondStructCollection()
    {
        var myList = new List<Structure2>();
        myList.Add(new Structure2
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Saphire Doe",
            Description = "struct 2 test"
        });

        myList.Add(new Structure2
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Onyx Doe",
            Description = "struct 2 test"
        });

        return new ObservableCollection<Structure1>(myList);
    }

    // this wont work....
    public ObservableCollection<object> GetDataByIndex(int pIndex)
    {
        ObservableCollection<object> data;

        if (pIndex == 1)
        {
            data = GetFirstStructCollection();      
        }

        if (pIndex == 2)
        {
            data = GetSecondStructCollection();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Which is called by

```
public class MyMain
{

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var job = new VmOne();

        var data = job.GetDataByIndex(1);

        // .... do something useful with the data
    }
}
```

I have not been able to figure out a way to do this. Can this be done? Just need a little direction.

The use of the data is as follows, the user selects a discipline that they wish to maintain.  Each discipline can have 2 or more data tables associated to it.  They can step through the data tables to perform maintenance.  Each table has their own unique structure.  I want to use a common UI so that they only need to select a discipline which will load the appropriate tables to be maintained.

In order to do this I have the table names in an array and when they select from the drop down the index will point to the array which has a table name.  I then want to call my method using either an index or the table name to return back the collection of data.  Since this is a WPF app the data is returned in an ObservableCollection .

So the method would return any combination of ObservableColleciton types....

Comment: [Look into generic methods](http://www.dotnetperls.com/generic-method)

Comment: so... use the data structures as the T?

Comment: Can you share an interface between Structure1 and Structure2 and work against that instead? In that case your GetDataByIndex is a factory and simply returns an instance of each interface, but you don't have to know which it is, since they work against the same interface.

Comment: Please show the definition of `Structure1` and `Structure2`; perhaps you have defined types with idential semantics.

Comment: How are you going to manipulate the data if you only access it via `object`?

Comment: @Patrick - In the larger scheme of things I will have at least 10 unique structures that get used across 11 variations.  I cant really create an Interface that will cover that kind of contract.

Comment: From what I can see from your snippet, Structure1 and Structure2 look very similar. Have a base class or interface for the 2 and work with that in your GetStructureCollection

Comment: @codor - see my comment to Patrick.

Comment: @barca - admittedly the structures do look similar, but in real life they aren't... bad example on my part.

Comment: @Kix: But, what are you going to do with the data you get from `GetDataByIndex`? If you don't have any contract against it you basically need to typecheck and dispatch it somewhere else, right? I think the problem needs to be elaborated to suggest a proper solution, otherwise this is close to be an XY-problem.

Comment: So, from what I understand you have a lot of these structures, which do not share common stuff, but you want to manipulate all of them by using one method instead of one for each structure. Using generics is your best bet

Comment: @barca - I am getting the feeling I am going to have to refactor a little on this.

Comment: You kind of left out the important stuff when you wrote "do something useful with the data". The answer depends on how you intend to access the collection. How does `DoSomething` know that `data` is a collection of `Structure1` as opposed to a collection of `Structure2`? For all it knows, it could be a collection of `int`.

Comment: @Raymond - what happens to the data at that point isn't entirely relevant.  My concern is getting the data that I need based on the index.  The data could go to a grid, be manipulated, etc... Looking over the responses I think I need to rework/refactor my design.

Comment: It is relevant because knowing how you intend to access the data will change the solutions. Are you planning on casting every element to `Structure1`? But what if the parameter to `GetDataByIndex` was a variable?

Comment: @Raymond - my need is to be able to return an ObservableCollection<T>  where T could be 1 of 10 datastructures/tables. I want to be able to either pass an index to indicate which to fetch the data for.  The class the method resides in will have several methods to do the actual fetch.  So I want to point to the one the index relates to.

Comment: The code that passes the 1, 2, 3, ... 10: Is it hard-coding the number, or did it come from a variable? If it came from a variable, how does it know what kind of collection it has? If it's always a hard-coded number, then you don't need the switch statement; just have 10 methods.

Comment: @Raymond - the index is a number based on the number of tables/datastructures for a discipline.  For example, discipline A uses 3 tables so index values will be 1-3, discipline B uses 7 tables to index values would run 1-7.. etc...  What discipline the user selects will determine the index value range.

Comment: You're not answering the question. Will the index ever be a variable, or will it always be a constant?

Comment: It will be variable.

Comment: Then how will the code know whether the result is a collection of `Structure1` or `Structure2`? If it will do a switch statement on the variable, then you can call a different method under that switch statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe try something along these lines, although your specifications are vague and a bit unclear:

```
void Main()
{
   // call it
   VmOne vmOne = new VmOne();
   vmOne.GetDataByIndex<Structure1>(GetStructCollection<Structure1>());

   // ...
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class VmOne
{
     public ObservableCollection<TStruct> GetStructCollection<TStruct>() where TStruct : class //     or base class for the structures if you can do it
    {
        var myList = new List<TStruct>();
       // add to list somehow
       return new ObservableCollection<TStruct>(myList);
     }

    public ObservableCollection<TStruct> GetDataByIndex<TStruct>(System.Action getStructCollection) where TStruct : class
    {
         ObservableCollection<TStruct> data = getStructCollection<TStruct>();   

        // ...

        return data;
     }
}
```

Bear in mind this is merely a sketch of what you could try to do

Comment: Actually this looks interesting.  I was getting stuck on the generics.  I have the classes for the structures from my EF setup ,,, will have to play around with it.

Comment: Try to think about problems you may encounter a few steps ahead. The answer to your qustion depends very much on the actual context of your problem. Think about how these structures relate to each other. From your question, I understood that you wanted some sort of strategy pattern implementation, that can be achieved with delegates (Action/Func) nicely in C# (and generics probably)

Answer (score 2):

i think you cannot do that the way you are looking for.
If you define a class(of t) (vb) oder class (c#), then you can create a method dosomething, which then gives you back a generic thing.

I would suggest to define an interface, that structure1 and structure2 do implement, and let your function return an observablecollection of your interface.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Are you here about varianza?  `ObservableCollection<T>` are not co-vantiant, this mean that you can pass an `ObservableCollection<Tk>` where Tk are inherit from T. Notice that you can do this with arrays.

```
object[] data1 = new Structure1[0];  // is valid becuase array are covariant
ObservableCollection<Structure> data2 = new ObservableCollection<Structure1>();  // compilation error becuase ObservableCollection are not covariant
```

You can use arrays and the create the `ObservableCollection<object>` like this:

```
private Structure1[] GetFirstStructCollection()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new Structure1
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "John Doe",
                Description = "struct 1 test"
            },
            new Structure1
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Sally Doe",
                Description = "struct 1 test"
            }
        };
    }

    private Structure2[] GetSecondStructCollection()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new Structure2
            {
                Id = 1,
            Name = "Saphire Doe",
            Description = "struct 2 test"
            },
            new Structure2
            {
                Id = 2,
            Name = "Onyx Doe",
            Description = "struct 2 test"
            }
        };
    }

        public ObservableCollection<object> GetDataByIndex2(int pIndex)
        {
            ObservableCollection<object> data = null;
            if (pIndex == 1)
            {
                data = new ObservableCollection<object>(GetFirstStructCollection());
            }

            if (pIndex == 2)
            {
                data = new ObservableCollection<object>(GetSecondStructCollection());
            }
            return data;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to what you want using generics:

```
class Zoo
    {
        public ObservableCollection<T> GetData<T>() where T : class
        {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Cat))
            return new ObservableCollection<T>(this.GetCatCollection().Cast<T>().ToList());
            // or:
            // return new ObservableCollection<T>(Cat.GetDefaultCollection().Cast<T>().ToList());

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Dog))
            return new ObservableCollection<T>(Dog.GetDefaultCollection().Cast<T>().ToList());

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Lion))
            return new ObservableCollection<T>(Lion.GetDefaultCollection().Cast<T>().ToList());

        return null;

        // pseudo-switch version
        //ObservableCollection<T> result = null;

        //var @switch = new Dictionary<Type, Action> {
        //{ typeof(Cat), () => result = new ObservableCollection<T>(Cat.GetDefaultCollection().Cast<T>().ToList()) },
        //{ typeof(Dog), () => result =  new ObservableCollection<T>(Dog.GetDefaultCollection().Cast<T>().ToList())},
        //{ typeof(Lion), () => result = new ObservableCollection<T>(Lion.GetDefaultCollection().Cast<T>().ToList())}};

        //@switch[typeof(T)]();

        //return result;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Cat> GetCatCollection()
    {
            ObservableCollection<Cat> list = new ObservableCollection<Cat>();
            list.Add(new Cat { CatName = "Cat No. 1" });
            list.Add(new Cat { CatName = "Cat No. 2" });
            list.Add(new Cat { CatName = "Cat No. 3" });
            return list;
    }

}

class Cat
{
    public string CatName { get; set; }

    public static ObservableCollection<Cat> GetDefaultCollection()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Cat> list = new ObservableCollection<Cat>();
        list.Add(new Cat { CatName = "Cat No. 1" });
        list.Add(new Cat { CatName = "Cat No. 2" });
        list.Add(new Cat { CatName = "Cat No. 3" });
        return list;
    }
}

class Dog
{
    public string DogName { get; set; }

    public static ObservableCollection<Dog> GetDefaultCollection()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Dog> list = new ObservableCollection<Dog>();
        list.Add(new Dog { DogName = "Dog No. 1" });
        list.Add(new Dog { DogName = "Dog No. 2" });
        list.Add(new Dog { DogName = "Dog No. 3" });
        return list;
    }
}
class Lion
{
    public string LionName { get; set; }

    public static ObservableCollection<Lion> GetDefaultCollection()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Lion> list = new ObservableCollection<Lion>();
        list.Add(new Lion { LionName = "Lion No. 1" });
        list.Add(new Lion { LionName = "Lion No. 2" });
        list.Add(new Lion { LionName = "Lion No. 3" });
        return list;
    }
}
```

Example use:

```
    var zoo = new Zoo();

    ObservableCollection<Cat> cats = zoo.GetData<Cat>();
    ObservableCollection<Dog> dogs = zoo.GetData<Dog>();
    ObservableCollection<Lion> lions = zoo.GetData<Lion>();


    Console.WriteLine("-------------- Cats:");
    cats.ToList().ForEach(cat => Console.WriteLine(cat.CatName));
    Console.WriteLine("-------------- Dogs:");
    dogs.ToList().ForEach(dog => Console.WriteLine(dog.DogName));
    Console.WriteLine("-------------- Lions:");
    lions.ToList().ForEach(lion => Console.WriteLine(lion.LionName));
```

result:

```
-------------- Cats:
Cat No. 1
Cat No. 2
Cat No. 3
-------------- Dogs:
Dog No. 1
Dog No. 2
Dog No. 3
-------------- Lions:
Lion No. 1
Lion No. 2
Lion No. 3
```